# Where do you put the relative url in a jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I have to reference my two html documents in divs to a primary html and I can't get my other htmls to render.

This is my script in the head:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

These are the divs in the body:

```
    <div id="left"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#left').load("left.html");
    });
    </script>

    <div id="right"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#right').load("right.html");
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your script to the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#left').load("left.html");
  $('#right').load("right.html");
});
</script>
```

Then ensure that your relative URIs are correct. Are both `left.html` and `right.html` in the same folder on the server as the page that requires them?

Comment: Doesn't really matter where this document.ready-script is located. :-) However, the question if left and right.html are actually in the same folder on the server will probably point to the root of your problem.

Comment: do I have to replace '$<document)" or "(funtion()'? I didn't actually put anything in that.

Comment: @user2617514 you should remove both of the `<script>` tags you posted in the Question, and use this single one instead. As @UweB stated, it doesn't matter where you place it, but the head is as good a spot as any.

Comment: Which <script> tags are you talking about? The one that was initially in the head or the one that I'm putting there?

Comment: @user2617514 The tag that is already in the head needs to stay there, untouched. The **two** that are in the body need to be removed, and the **one** in my answer placed into your page instead.

Comment: Alright, it still isn't working though. I don't know what to do.

Comment: @user2617514 Did you confirm that the relative URIs are correct?

Comment: Yes. I don't need to write $('left.html").load('left.html'); right? I can leave out the '.html' in the former?

Comment: @user2617514 Copy it exactly as it appears in my answer. If it does not work, then your URIs are wrong.

Comment: @user2617514 Is the scenario in the question the same as on your site? Are the `right.html` and `left.html` pages in the same folder as the page that's requesting them?

Comment: Yes.They are in the same folder.

Comment: @user2617514 Then this is a problem outside the scope of what someone could fix without being able to troubleshoot directly.